# encoding issue with CSV.parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastercsv

My goal is to upload a file containing rows of firstname and lastname, parse it and create Person model in db for each row.

I do the following and it works fine

```
file = CSV.parse(the_file_to_parse)
file.each do |row|
  person = Person.new(:firstname => row[0], :lastname => row[1])
  person.save
end
```

until my file contains accents (french words), I get

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8:
INSERT INTO "people" ("created_at", "firstname", "lastname",
"updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

What is the best way to deal with this encoding issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the csv file with the right encoding.  For example:

```
require 'csv'
require 'pp'

encoding = "ISO-8859-1"

csv = CSV.open "names.csv", "rb:#{encoding}"
csv.each do |line|
    puts "#{line[0]} #{line[1]}"
end
```

Here's a hint: it's probably not UTF-8.

The list of encodings that your ruby supports can be viewed with this command in irb:

```
puts Encoding.list.map(&:to_s).sort
```

Comment: I've got ArgumentError: 'mode' must be 'r', 'rb', 'w', or 'wb'

Answer (score 0):

try to set

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

on the top of ruby file. or

```
export RUBYOPT=-Ku
```

before rails s

Answer (score 0):

If you have no clue about the encoding of the input file you might try [ensure_encoding](https://github.com/Manfred/Ensure-encoding).

It will try to guess the input encoding and try (does not work for all encodings) to convert it to your preferred target encoding.